# ValueError: Please set your RAVE_SECRET_KEY environment variable. Otherwise, pass publicKey and secretKey as arguments and set usingEnv

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, flask-restful

I am trying to write unit and functional tests for my flask app using the pytest tool. I have this fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture
def app():
    os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = '/home/xxxxxxxx/Documents/dudu-docs/dudu-api/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.json'
    os.environ['CONFIG_TYPE'] = 'config.TestingConfig'
    os.environ['RAVE_SECRET_KEY'] = 'FLWSECK_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    os.environ['RAVE_PUBLIC_KEY'] = 'FLWPUBK_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    flask_app = create_app()
    flask_app.config['TESTING'] = True
    flask_app.config['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = os.getenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')

    # Create a test client using the Flask application configured for testing
    with flask_app.test_client() as testing_client:
        # Establish an application context
        with flask_app.app_context():
            yield testing_client  # this is where the testing happens!
```

and this is the actual test:

```
def test_is_valid_data_username_success(app):
    data = 'john_doe'
    mtype = 'username'
    result = is_valid_data(data=data, mtype=mtype)
    assert result == True
```

I am using the *flutterwave api* and adding the required keys via environmental variables in my code but getting this error:

```
raise ValueError(
E   ValueError: Please set your RAVE_SECRET_KEY environment variable. Otherwise, pass publicKey and secretKey as arguments and set usingEnv to false
collected 0 items / 1 error
```

My current IDE is pycharm, but using the terminal command `pytest ...` still gives the above error. I need help identifying why my *RAVE* variables aren't being picked up.

Answer (score 0):

The error says `Please set your RAVE_SECRET_KEY environment variable`, it looks like `RAVE_SECRET_KEY` is spelt incorrectly when setting the env.

```
os.environ['RAVE_SECRETE_KEY'] = 'FLWSECK_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

should probably be

```
os.environ['RAVE_SECRET_KEY'] = 'FLWSECK_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Comment: corrected it but still the same error

Comment: The issue was due to a lack of discovery for the environment variables, a simple way to solve that is to load environment variables from the `.env` file. I prefer to use [python-decouple](https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/) to load my `.env`, refer to the link for usage.